# Versioning of DataContract/ServiceContract in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

We have delivered WCF service to production with a certain DataContract and SerivceContract. 
But now we need to change both SerivceContract and DataContract a bit. One of our consumer has no ability to update the contract. But we need to support both old client and new clients on the same address. How to do that?

Old contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICoolerService
{
     [OperationContract]
     IEnumerable<Cooler> Get(IEnumerable<int> ids)
}
```

New contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICoolerService
{
     [OperationContract]
     IEnumerable<Cooler> Get(IEnumerable<CoolerRequest> req)
}

[DataContract]
public class CoolerRequest
{
     [DataMember]
     public int Id { get; set; }
     //and some more properties
}
```

Please advise how to support both contracts on the same uri.

Comment: One of way is make method which return version of contracts. And if is newer than saved on clients side, automatic download new referenced updates to client side. We using this and its working perfectly. Every client has actual version.

Comment: Unfortunatly, we haven't acces to the client code :(

Comment: So, it is not possible. If you change contracts on server side and you want to use changes on client side, you have to update references on client side.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just leave the old overload in place?

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ICoolerService
{
     [OperationContract]
     IEnumerable<Cooler> Get(IEnumerable<int> ids);

     [OperationContract]
     IEnumerable<Cooler> Get(IEnumerable<CoolerRequest> req);
}
```

Comment: This wont work. It will compile but it will throw an exception at runtime when a call is made to that Operation Contract.

Comment: It doesn't work, unfortunatly. When service starts I have an exception: Cannot have two operations in the same contract with the same name, methods Get and Get in type CoolerService.ICoolerService violate this rule. You can change the name of one of the operations by changing the method name or by using the Name property of OperationContractAttribute.

Comment: Well it sounds like that is your answer then: if you cannot have two services with the same name, then you will have to change one of them. Why can't you change the name of the new service?

Comment: It will break well formed logical path of uri. We expect to have only one version in future and we don't wont to have prefic /v1/ and /v2/ in our uri, it's kind of requeirement from management. Of course, if it's not possbile we will change the uri...

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Versioning Windows Communication Foundation Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigmcmurtry/archive/2006/07/23/676104.aspx)

It talks about using **Service Contract Inheritance** for new Operation
And also about modifying an existing operation and data contracts

Comment: I don't need to add an operation, I need to change it, but want to avoid braeking old clients.